# Maven Project Build Error: Could not calculate build plan

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have created a new maven project and when I am trying to do the the following steps:

1. Right click on the project
2. Maven
3. Update Project

I get the below error

[image]

Until and unless this issue gets resolved i am not able to look into other errors as the issue occurs during the build itself.

I downloaded the required jar and pom and put it in the repository still the issue is present. Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

This error usually occurs when there is a clash of the jar version that you may be using or most probably the JDK versions that you may be using.

I suggest the best option would be to delete your local .m2 directory and install all the jars once again to fix this issue. most of the times this trick works